# How does Keras produce output of different size y, given an input of size x?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to neural network here. I am reading a lot of guides and tutorial where they will start with an lstm layer where the input size differs from the output size

eg. model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(20, 1))) ->
before doing ->

- model.add(Dense(80, activation='relu')), etc.

presumably, the output layer for the lstm here has size 100, where the input has only 20
for a dense layer I can imagine how that works because there are plenty of graphs depicting that, but how can a lstm produce output layer of very different size from the input?

- and also importantly, of what range of value can the output be given the input (let's say of 20) effectively be? would any value make sense?

Comment: There are no limits in term of output size given input, so I think your question is based on a misconception. The "how" is just a matrix multiplication.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Not sure how I offended anyone with my question but ok.

Answer (score 0):

The output size can be anything. For example, in case of feeding word embeddings of 256 length and output size 1000 length, it somewhat follows the below steps:

1. Embedding goes into the LSTM (Here, I am ignoring the batch and sequence length; just one word embedding in one time-step)
2. The Weight Matrix (Waa, Way, Wax etc are initialized) : These matrices shapes depends upon the output size you gave (e.g. 100 above)
3. All the needed calculations are followed as per LSTM semantics
4. The output of 1000 vector length is generated